# how to row reduce a matrix using Gaussian elimination?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

(don't give me the full answer, but only hints, since I need to come up with the solution by myself)

I have to implement Gaussian elimination in C,

this is how I designed matrix:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct matrix {
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    double* data; /* data is a pointer of type double, I have to allocate it to store rows * cols entries. */
};

void matrix_constructor(struct matrix* m, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    m -> rows = rows;
    m->cols = cols;
    m->data = calloc(rows * cols, sizeof(double));
}

void matrix_destructor(struct matrix* m) {
    free(m->data);
}
```

and this is the gaussian_elimination function:

```
void gaussian_elimination(struct matrix* m) {
size_t rows = m->rows;
size_t cols = m->cols; 
double* data = m->data; 
/* data[r*cols+c] gives me the entry of the matrix (it's stored in the array "data") */
for (size_t r = 0; 1 /* infinity loop */; ++r) {
    for (size_t c = 0; 1 /* infinity loop */; ++c) {
        if (data[r * cols + c] < data[(r + 1) * cols + c]) {
            for (size_t c_one = 0; c_one < cols; ++c) {
                data[(r + 1) * cols + c] -= data[r * cols + c];
            }
        } /* if data[] >= data[+1] */
        if (data[r * cols + c] >= data[(r + 1) * cols + c]) {
            for (size_t c_two = 0; c_two < cols; ++c) {
                data[r * cols + c] -= data[(r + 1) * cols + c]; 
            }
        }
        
     }
    }
}
```

the function is not complete, because I don't know how to proceed further. but that's the idea: because I used infinity loops (since I don't know how many iterations are required to row reduce the matrix), I used an if to check whether or not I got lines with all zeros. If this condition holds, then (break), and go outside the loop. But I don't know how to formalize this thought in mathematical notation (mathematical notation will allow me to translate this thought in a C-oriented thought).
But I think I got the key concept:

- in the last if-statement, use a for-loop, and then check if each entry is either zero or not. if there's at least one non-zero entry, then keep iterating the loop; otherwise "break".
- I think I have to start checking non-zero entries from the last row of the matrix. (because, recall, in linear algebra, when I have a reduced matrix I have the last line/s with all zeros).

I have another question:

- how can I formalize the concept of "let the compiler to decide whether or not swap two rows together and when subtract two rows together"? This is the main question, even though it's simple (and I think it's simple), I can't figure it out by myself.

Comment: A plain array in C is not very suitable for storing a mathematical matrix where you may add and remove rows etc. An array of pointers to rows might be more flexible. Generally, don't make the mistake of taking some abstract math concept and bringing it into the very practical down-to-earth C language. C is not Matlab.

Comment: You could for example make it a `double**` pointing to the first item of a `malloc( sizeof(double* [rows][cols]) )` array, where each pointer points at a row. This would enable fast deletion, re-ordering, transposing and whatever you want to do. My linear algebra is very rusty I'm afraid, or I'd post a proper answer.

Comment: "You could for example make it a double** pointing to the first item of a malloc( sizeof(double* [rows][cols]) ) array", so i have to change the struct too? Or can I create a pointer to pointer to double directly in the function?

Comment: @Lundin Array of arrays is fast if one needs to re-order rows. For nearly anything else (transposing, re-ordering *columns*) the advantage is gone as one needs to address individual cells in the arrays anyway – or even on side of the single array because of avoiding double indirection...

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini If it's not for efficiency then the *nice* thing about array of arrays is that you can use the double index operator on them: `data[row][column]`. *This* is what I'd consider the benefit for why you might want to switch to that data structure as Lundin recommends (simpler and thus better maintainable code).

Comment: If you opt for the 1D array (from performance point of view I'd rather prefer that one *unless* you indeed reorder entire rows pretty often) you might want to introduce an `at` function (`index`, `cell` or whatever better name you find) so that you don't have to repeat the index calculation code again: `double d = getCell(matrix, row, column)` as `{ return matrix->data[row * matrix->cols + column]; }`.

Comment: or use a dynamic VLA. `double (*data)[cols] = calloc(rows, sizeof *data);`. It will  avoid indirection and supports `data[i][j]` notation. Note that it is not supported by MSVC compiler.

Comment: @Aconcagua are you talking about the subtracting calculations? "matrix" in the first field is the pointer of type struct matrix, right?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini You refer to the cell getter? `double cell(struct matrix* m, size_t row, size_t column) {...}`.

Comment: @tstanisl And how would you declare the struct then? Because the struct needs to cover that. I could imagine casting (`double(*data)[m->cols] = (double(*)[m->cols]) m->data`) if it remains a 1D double array – not sure, though, if that's legal at all...

Comment: @Aconcagua, use good old `void*`. When accessing the matrix cast its data to a pointer to VLA. Macro may help: `MAT2VLA(MAT, VAR);` -> `double (*VAR)[MAT->cols] = MAT->data;`.

Comment: @tstanisl Not sure if I should like that or not. On the other hand I'm not too happy about the `cellAt` function either. At this point I'm missing C++ where I could define my own operator[] and a proxy type with yet another operator[] – which would cover that more nicely.

Comment: @Aconcagua, `double (*data)[cols] = m->data;`  is not much longer than `double* data = m->data;`. And you get all the cool stuff :)

Comment: @tstanisl Well, the macro is better, having to define the pointer to array is error prone, at least for not that versed programmers...